# Typescript strict mode cannot assign Observable async to primeNg dropdown component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, ngrx-entity, primeng-dropdowns

I am using the p-dropdown primeNg component and from what I can see this should be able to take an Observable | async value and use it properly but the Typescript strict mode will not allow this, giving

**error TS2322: Type 'Customers[] | null is not assignable to type 'any[]'"**

customers.html

```
<p-dropdown
[options]="customers$ | async"
placeholder="Select a customer:"
optionLabel="name"
[showClear]=true"
formControlName=selectedCustomer"
</p-dropdown>
```

customers.component.ts

```
customers$!: Observable<Customer[]>;
ciForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private: fb: FormBuilder, private customerEntityService: CustomerEntityService){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.ciForm = this.fb.group({
       selectedCustomer: [null],
       selectedReason: [null],
       selectedId: [null],
       comments: ['']
    });

    this.ciCustomers$ = this.customerEntityService.entities$
    .pipe(
       map(customer => customer)
    );
}
```

customer.model.ts

```
export class Customer {
    public name: string = '';
    public phoneNumber: string = '';
}
```

I was under the impression that using the "!" after the variable denoted that it definitely will have a value, which is the case since the data is being fetched in the route resolve prior to loading the component, but this doesn't seem to matter to the compiler.  Any help as to how to fix this?  I am at my wits end on this. The primeNg community forums seem to be of no assistance in getting this resolved either.

I know I probably can declare another variable and subscribe to the data in the entityCache and then pass that data to the options but the whole point of the async pipe is that I shouldn't HAVE to do that.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I need to do to fix the null issue?

Comment: Where are you setting/filling customers$..?

Comment: @MikeOne in the resolve for the route, but that isn't relevant to why it won't build.

Comment: `$any(name$ | async)` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async pipe returns data type or null. What you need to do is to use `*ngIf="customers$ | async as customers" [options]="customers"`.

You could also use a container around you code and add the structured directive there.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure why I didn't think of this but it works without issues!

Answer (score -1):

test on -- angular 14 + primng 14
you can add the ***"!"*** typescript operator to prevent null checks
and to prevent null you can add rxjs operator startWith([]) to your code

```
<p-dropdown [options]="(customers$ | async)!" </p-dropdown>
```

Comment: someomr gave me DEVOTE - but i repeat i check my answer and it is working good

Comment: It should be like this: [options]="(customers$ | async)!"

Comment: i fix and update my answer